# Adapter to convert a 45-degree angle wall electrical plug into a straight plug

Tags: electrical, cord-and-plug, extension-cord, adapter

This is a recurring problem I have: Instead of a traditional, straight plug, I have devices with a three-prong plug that lays flush against a wall and angled at 45 degrees. I find these types of plugs quite annoying because they only work if the electrical socket is in exactly the right orientation.

So, I need a way "straighten" out the plug. What would be perfect is something that rotates 360 degrees, similar to these extension cords, but without the cord: [https://www.amazon.com/Nekteck-Listed-Extension-Degree-Rotating/dp/B071KSM5DQ](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B071KSM5DQ)

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean like a rotating receptacle? https://amzn.to/3eBpCix

Comment: Ah, sorry I should have also clarified: I'd like a solution that is portable, so it can be plugged into a wall socket, extension cord, surge protector, etc. So something similar, but that is not affixed to the wall.

Comment: I like those plugs, since they lay flat against the wall and the cords don't interfere with adjacent plugs.

Comment: @HotLicks they're great if the cord goes to the left, and the device being used is to the left of the plug, if not and you've got to twist a stiff cord around into a tight ~180 degree bend, not so much.

Comment: @NoSparksPlease That rotating receptacle (according to the top review) causes sparks.

Comment: Do you mean 45 degree, or 90 degree?  I can't imagine a 45 degree angle; that would basically come diagonally out of the wall.  Nearly every cord I've ever see is 90 degree (flat against the wall) or straight.

Comment: I think they mean 45 degrees offset from the norm *in the other plane* (I've seen it before on right angle plugs)

Answer (score 7):

Simplest and most reliable option (no sliding contacts required) is a 1 foot extension cord (or a longer one, but 1 foot will get the desired degree of freedom.)

Comment: Personally, I find those plugs are normally superior to the straight kind and have no problems fitting them on any normal receptacle or strip. They don't do well with  the center of 2x3 6-outlet expanders, though.

Comment: I am having trouble see how this would fix the issue: The female end of the extension cord will just inherit the same problems as the original socket, no? Is there a 1' extension cord with a rotating female socket.

Comment: The **cord** flexes and rotates.

Comment: do they *make* 1-foot extension cords?

Comment: Yes, easily found.

Answer (score 5):

### Flip the electrical socket over

Turn main breaker off, make sure both sockets are dead, 1 coverplate screw, 2 yoke screws, rotate 180, put it back in.  Don't even need to take the wires off (actually: don't).

Now your appliance cord is working as intended: giving a flush-to-wall socket that you can back furniture up against, yet allowing both sockets to be used.

### Or use an appliance-grade extension cord that is UL-listed.

The other way to deal with it is use a large-appliance-grade extension cord (just a foot or two long will suffice) that is UL-listed, and is 12-14 AWG, and has a "plug end" that you want.

### DO NOT use crud from Amazon

Every product recommended here has been an "Amazon Marketplace" item sold *definitely not* by Amazon, but by some third party vendor.  This part of the Amazon listings are "basically eBay" in terms of quality and reliability.  Most of that stuff will "burn your house down" and indeed, reviews are littered with reports of the units burning up etc.

Answer (score 4):

I know exactly what you mean, those plugs are just a nuisance most of the time.  @Ecnerwal's answer using a short extension cord is going to be the simplest and cheapest way to work around this.

Another option - I will often re-terminate cords to get them the exact length I want, you could do the same to get a regular straight plug.  A decent quality UL listed NEMA 5-15P plug is still pretty inexpensive.  They're a little bulkier than I'd like but they're easy to use and very strong if you assemble it right.

[image: nema 5-15p plug]

Comment: I find the "Valise" style better because it is square, even though it is still bulky.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t understand why Ecnerwal’s Answer doesn’t provide a solution to your problem.
But here is a [portable adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000VWAL7E)
with the rotating socket.

[image: Pic]

Comment: Beware. This particular product shows **NO EVIDENCE OF UL LISTING OR ANYTHING SIMILAR** on the product page on Amazon and while most people seem satisfied, a couple of the reviews are pretty scary.

Comment: I'm wondering if that sort of device *can* be made safely at a reasonable price.  Any sort of wear in the rotating connections could result in poor connections and arcing.  It'd fail the conversation piece/cool trick feature; but a fixed 180 degree adapter would be much easier to make safely.  Even there though I'd be concerned about who made it, and expect a significant fraction of Chinese Excrement certified devices to do a direct pass-through for the blade plugs only relocating the ground pin and end up delivering reversed polarity power.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving 2 Codidact - a quick googling leads to the manufacturer, https://360electrical.com, a US company based in Salt Lake City. I suspect they have UL listing and they can be checked for sure.

Comment: @Gábor I did see that too. But I am still skeptical based on (a) no evidence of UL (or similar) listing in the Amazon page (the ones that have it normally make sure to mention it, as it is quite important) and (b) some pretty scary reviews (with pictures even). I did not say "don't buy". I said "beware". If someone can show evidence to the contrary, I'd remove even that. But at the moment, I am still skeptical and "beware".